# Integration adtech windows phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

Hello everyone I am trying to integrate adtech sdk on windows phone 8. I have the sample app which works prefectly.

When i am trying to add the configuration in my App.xaml

```
   <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TransitionPageStyle" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
            <Setter Property="toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
                        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
                        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
                        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
                        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
                        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
                        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CineOrangeWP8" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>

        <ResourceDictionary xmlns:adtech="clr-namespace:Adtech.Windows.Phone.Sdk.Configuration;assembly=Adtech.Mobile.SDK.Library">
            <adtech:DefaultAdConfiguration x:Key="DefaultAdConfiguration"
                                            Animation="TOP_TO_BOTTOM"
                                            ApplicationName="appanme"
                                            Domain="a.adtech.de"
                                            NetworkId="23"
                                            SubnetworkId="4"
                                            RefreshInterval="30"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

I am getting this error

> Each dictionary entry must have an associated key.

here

```
>  <ResourceDictionary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move all your resources inside `<ResourceDictionary>` :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns:adtech="clr-namespace:Adtech.Windows.Phone.Sdk.Configuration;assembly=Adtech.Mobile.SDK.Library">
        <adtech:DefaultAdConfiguration x:Key="DefaultAdConfiguration"
                                        Animation="TOP_TO_BOTTOM"
                                        ApplicationName="appanme"
                                        Domain="a.adtech.de"
                                        NetworkId="23"
                                        SubnetworkId="4"
                                        RefreshInterval="30"/>
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CineOrangeWP8" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
        <Style x:Key="TransitionPageStyle" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
            .......
            .......
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```